# Confusion with QQ plots

Tags: statistics

I've got some difficulty understanding QQ plots and the specific slope and intercept of the line which the data will approximate if it really is generated from the distribution we're comparing with.

I've got a dataset $A$ and the dataset $B = log(A)$ seems to be normally distributed, as the QQ plot shows me a straight line.... but this line has slope 1 and intercept 0? I thought it was supposed to have slope $\sigma$ and intercept $\mu$?

Similarly, if we then compare $A$ with data simulated from the log normal distribution with parametes $\mu$ and $\sigma$, I again get a scatterplot that approximates the $x = y$ line....

What does this mean? I thought I'd only get above if my data was standardnormal distributed, but it's not (the mean for $B$, for example, is 8, and not near 0)?

Edit: Okay, it seems I've misunderstood $\texttt{R}$ as opposed to the theory behind QQ-plots. The command $\texttt{qqplot(x,y)}$ shows a scatterplot of $x,y$ and if they are identically distributed, they'll lie around a line. The command $\texttt{qqnorm(x)}$ will be the one that lies around a straight line with slope and intercept given by the parameters. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several very well written posts on the topic of QQ plots on the stats.stackexchange website. Here are a few written by moderators and members alike:

[How to interpret a QQ plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/101274/192854)

[Interpreting QQplot - Is there any rule of thumb to decide for non-normality?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111010/interpreting-qqplot-is-there-any-rule-of-thumb-to-decide-for-non-normality)

[R - QQPlot: how to see whether data are normally distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52293/r-qqplot-how-to-see-whether-data-are-normally-distributed)

To answer your question partially, indeed the command in R for the qq plot is "qqnorm" and potentially "qqline"